# how to declare local data dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i have data

```
chal: {
        one: "",
        two: "",
        three: "",
        four: "",
        five: "",
        six: "",
        seven: "",
        eight: "",
        nine: ""
      }
```

and return data from backend is array
i am trying foreach data

```
res.data.foreach(chal => {

   //chal is number string
   // how to declare here chal.one == x
                               ^^^
                               this
});
```

Comment: Why would you assign to `chal`? It's the value from the array in the current iteration. And what is `x`? And `==`  evaluates the value, it does not assign it. Please review your question, it's very poor quality.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici `chal.box` is `one` result not `X`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys()`.

```
Object.keys(res.data.chal).foreach(key => {
   console.log(res.data.chal[key]);
});
```